# Two processes write to a shared memory

Tags: c, memory, process, shared

I have to resolve problem two producer and one consument with semaphores and shared memory in C, Linux. 
I have three processes : first process is producer, second process is producer, and third process is consument.

Producers are reading from own files and write it in one buffer. Consument has to read from buffer and write in stdout.

My problem is: how to in second producer writing to buffer on proper position? 
I show some code maybe:
first producer:

```
    while( fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp) ){

    wait(semid,0);

for(i=0;i<1000 && line[i]!='\0';i++){
        buf[i]=line[i];
    }
signal(semid,1);


}

fclose (fp); // close file


signal(semid,1);
```

Second producer is this same(except semaphores)... How to write in buffer at proper position(after first producer)?...

Consumer:

```
while(1){
    wait(semid,2);
    printf("\n Proces K: ");
    for (i=0; i<1000 && buf[i]!='\n'; i++){
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }



    signal(semid,0);
```

Comment: Store the next address to write in inside the buffer, equally protected by your semaphore.

Comment: what do you mean? i don't understand this solution

Comment: You need [i] to be shared as well; not just buf.

Answer (score 0):

I am used struct as shared memory, where I have array and counter.

It is the best way to resolve this problem i think. Now my program works good. Thanks for comments.